# Find and Get SQL value only match multiple column PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to get value from sql based on matched keywords for multiple column. Here is my example.

table_movies

```
id |  title    |  year  | url
-----------------------------
1  | Title 1   | 1996   | http://url1.com

2  | Title 2   | 2004   | http://url2.com


3  | Title 1   | 2011   | http://url3.com


4  | Title 3   | 2018   | http://url4.com


$search = "Title 1";
$year = "2011";

$get = "SELECT FROM table_movies WHERE title ='$search'  and year='$year'"; 

if ($get == true){
echo "Title: " $get[title]; 
echo "Year: " $get[year]; 
echo "Url: " $get[url]; 
}
else
{
echo "not found"
}
```

output expected :

Title  : Title 1
Year   : 2011
Url    : http://url3.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add columns you want to select:

```
SELECT title, year, url
FROM table_movies WHERE title ='Title 1' and year='2011';
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a078490d650e28065d3dfe5ce65588e8)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply,Its works. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to help when possible. Cheers!